# Broadcom USB Bluetooth adapter not working

Tags: usb, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

I'm trying to make a Broadcom-based Bluetooth USB adapter work in Ubuntu 20.04 ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J5WFPXX), to be specific). And it just refuses to work. The symptoms are always the same: I get the following errors in my `kern.log`:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
```

I've downloaded and installed the firmware file from [Winterheart](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm) repo, even extracted and converted the firmware from Windows 8 driver package, but the result is still the same: the errors above and nothing showing up in the output of `hcitool dev`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Some diagnostic info below:

```
$ lsusb | grep Blu
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm' | cut -c 16-
Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
```

```
$ rfkill list
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ hcitool dev
Devices:
$
```

```
$ ll /lib/firmware/brcm/*21e8*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35934 Jun 13 03:43 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e8.hcd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34700 Jun 13 19:56 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd
```

**UPDATE:** Looks like it might be motherboard-related (AsRock P67 Extreme4 Gen3 in my case): trying the same adapter on a different laptop makes it work fine (as long as I provide firmware)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be motherboard-related. Only the USB 3.1 ports on the rear panel the motherboard seem to make this dongle work correctly - all other ports results in the errors above.